# PHP return from function for user in PHP

Tags: php, function, variables

Is it possible to (in some format), return a variable containing information from a function in PHP

eg.

```
function setuplogin($email,$pwd){
    if(!$email || !$pwd){ return $error = 'not possible'; }
}
```

So that on the page where it was called

```
<?php echo $error;?>
```

would work

EDIT:

It would not be possible to simply echo the function as this same function could also be set to 
`return $success = 'congrats';` and called on page with `<?php echo $success;?>`

Comment: It must be asked who would vote against a question containing a legitimate and likely to reoccur question of interest to many, written, titled and tagged correctly to the benefit of those learning to master PHP. Political interests perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to be able to return multiple things: whether the function succeeded or failed, and a message to go along with it. You can do that by returning an array:

```
return array('success' => true, 'message' => 'well done');
```

The caller can do:

```
$result = setuplogin(...);
echo $result['message'];
```

Answer (score 1):

A function can only return a value (of any type). What you do with that value - e.g. assigning it to a variable or to different variables depending on the value returned - is solely the job of the caller and the function cannot influence this.

Of course your function could create a global variable by assigning to `$GLOBALS['whatever']` but that's **extremely ugly** and if you call your function from another function it wouldn't even work the way you wanted. Another drawback would be that you'd always have to assign something to *all* of the variables - otherwise you'll end up with possibly undefined variables depending on what the function did and would need `isset()` checks in the code using those variables.

So what you are trying to do is not possible in a clean way. The closest would be retruning an array:

```
function foo() {
    return array('success' => ..., 'error' => ...);
}
```

Then the caller could do e.g. `$result = foo();` and then use `$result['success']` and `$result['error']`

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to check.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set up the function to spit out the variable you want without using a "variable".

```
function setuplogin($email,$pwd){
if(!$email || !$pwd){ return 'not possible'; }
}
```

```
<?php echo setuplogin(); ?>
```

Or you can use global variables and call the $error outside the function:

```
$error = "";
function setuplogin($email,$pwd){
global $error;
if(!$email || !$pwd){ $error = 'not possible'; }
}

<?php echo $error; ?>
```

Of course the second one assumes that you would call the function before the echo.

Comment: No. Let me be more specific. Using the same function I may want to return $success = 'well done'; and call <?php echo $success;?> on the page

Comment: Global variables? For ...'s sake, no! Don't do that!

Comment: It might be exactly what he is looking for regardless of how good of an idea it is @ThiefMaster :/